# Weighted average across multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several dataframes of identical dimensions, say df1 and df2.

I want to create a third dataframe, say avg_df, that is a weighted average of the respective values in df1 and df2. Say I want to be df1 weighted with a factor of 2 and df2 with a factor of 1.

I have another problem, in that some columns are filled with strings (but identical across dataframes). But I somehow need to ignore those when averaging...

Some example code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["hello", 2, 1], ["hello", 1, 1]], columns=["a", "b", "c"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["hello", 2, 2], ["hello", 1, 1]], columns=["a", "b", "c"])
```

Manually typing up the result would be something like this (obviously not a feasible solution, just so that there is example code that produces the desired output):

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([["hello", (2*2+1*2)/3, (2*1+1*2)/3], ["hello", (2*1+1*1)/3, (2*1+1*1)/3]], columns=["a", "b", "c"])
```

How do I get there?

Thank you!!

Comment: please do not paste images of text; just the text will be fine. About your question: why are there two rows in your expected result?  What if the `a` columns contains several different strings?

Comment: In my case this cannot happen. So in my case you can just pick either string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to disregard the string column, and you are certain the two `df` are the same shape, then you can do this:

```
sel = ['b', 'c']  # numeric columns
df3 = df1.copy()
df3[sel] = 2/3 * df1[sel] + 1/3 * df2[sel]
```

On your data, `df3` is:

```
       a    b         c
0  hello  2.0  1.333333
1  hello  1.0  1.000000
```

However, in the more general case, you may have different sizes and your `a` column may be relevant.  Here is an example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["hello", 2, 1], ["world", 1, 1]], columns=["a", "b", "c"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["world", 2, 2], ["hello", 1, 1]], columns=["a", "b", "c"])

(2/3 * df1.set_index('a').stack() +
 1/3 * df1.set_index('a').stack()).groupby(level=[0,1]).mean().unstack().reset_index()

# gives:
       a    b    c
0  hello  2.0  1.0
1  world  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, nice and simple. Thank you!!
quick note: it should be 1/3*df2[sel] in your example code.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it, if you want to get mean based on the index of each row. You can achieve that by contacting the two dataframes and taking a mean of that dataframe.

```
In [10]: df_concat = pd.concat((df1,df2))                                                                                                                                                                   

In [11]: df_concat                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[11]: 
       a  b  c
0  hello  2  1
1  hello  1  1
0  hello  2  2
1  hello  1  1

In [12]: by_row_index = df_concat.groupby(df_concat.index)                                                                                                                                                  

In [13]: df_mean = by_row_index.mean()        

In [15]: df_mean                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[15]: 
     b    c
0  2.0  1.5
1  1.0  1.0

In [18]: result = pd.concat([df_mean,df1[["a"]]],axis=1)                                                                                                                                                    

In [19]: result                                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[19]: 
     b    c      a
0  2.0  1.5  hello
1  1.0  1.0  hello
```

Comment: This is already helpful, thanks! But this mean is not weighted like I need it to be. Is it possible to get the mean and declare some weights?